# Safely convert REAL to INT when values exceed INT range?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I'm working with a SQL Server database and I have a column `Quantity` in my `Product` table which is of `REAL` data type. I want to convert this column to `INT`, but some of the `REAL` values are greater than the maximum `INT` value (`2147483647`).

When I try to update the `Quantity` column with the following query:

```sql
UPDATE p
SET p.Quantity = CASE 
    WHEN p.Quantity > CAST(2147483647 AS REAL) THEN 2147483647
    ELSE CAST(p.Quantity AS INT)
END
FROM Product p WITH(ROWLOCK)
```

I get an arithmetic overflow error:

> Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 2147483648.000000

Moreover, when I set the `Quantity` as `2147483647` cast as `REAL`:

```sql
UPDATE Product
SET Quantity = CAST(2147483647 AS REAL) 
WHERE id = '123'
```

The `Quantity` becomes `2.147484E+09` (which is `2147483648` when converted use `STR(quantity)`), and the previous update query still fails with the same error.

How can I safely convert these `REAL` values to `INT` in SQL Server when some values exceed the `INT` range?

And if possible please explain me about the this

If I set quantity to a number 2147483xxx which 3 last number is in range `[584 -> 777)` it will become 2147483**658**

520: [457 -> 584)

658: [584 -> 777)

Comment: Why on earth are you storing quantities as real?

Comment: Use bigint instead of int?

Comment: my mistake. Cause at first i though there is something like 12.5kg will be stored as quantity

Comment: That should still be a decimal (like money), never a float, that's for scientific data only.

Comment: You last point is exactly why you don't use float, because it doesn't store a precise number.

Comment: And do you really have quantities that large? Or are they invalid?

Comment: @DaleK No the quantity is not that large but I need  to make sure the conversion is still working if there is some value greater than the maximum int

Comment: So bigint? You will almost certainly lose some info, but that what happens with float

Comment: I will try to use bigint

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256737/discussion-between-liap-and-dale-k).

Comment: How about `TRY_CAST()` -  `CASE WHEN WHEN TRY_CAST(p.Quantity AS INT) IS NULL THEN ...` or perhaps even `ISNULL(TRY_CAST(p.Quantity AS INT), 0x7FFFFFFF)`, where 0x7FFFFFFF yields the same integer result as 2147483648).

Comment: As for the strange rounding, this is the result of REAL being the lowest precision of the floating point numbers, supporting only about 7 digits of precision. (Internally it is represented as an IEEE 32 bit floating point value with bits allocated for sign and exponent, leaving only 24 bits for the mantissa that yields about 7 digits of precision. So when the integer value exceeds a certain value, precision is lost. In contrast, SQL server FLOAT is a 64 bit value with about 16 decimal digits of precision. Any INT value can be converted to FLOAT and back without precision loss.

Comment: A couple more thoughts: If your goal is to guarantee that the quantity values can safely be processed as integers (and you cannot change the current table definition) you might consider (1) Adding a check constraint to limit the range of values allowed in that column, or (2) Adding a persistent computed column called `IntQuantity` or similar that would always contain a safe integer value. You could then start transitioning your application(s) over to that column name.

Comment: I ended up with 3 solutions. (1) Change to `BigInt` like @DaleK comment. (2) Set quantity to `9_999_999` if it is over (cause the precision of REAL is 7 digits). (3) Set quantity to `[457 -> 584)` cause it will become `520` as the maximum value and it is not greater than max int. In MS SQL docs I found that REAL follows the IEEE 754 specification and uses `round up`. Now I have a question how does the REAL datatype number rounding work? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187912(v=sql.105)

Comment: Ask a new question

Comment: Just don't use REAL (or money) in sql server for anything and you'll be fine, it's for access coders

Answer (score 0):

Just use `TRY_CAST`

```sql
UPDATE p
SET p.Quantity = 2147483647
FROM Product p
WHERE TRY_CAST(p.Quantity AS INT) IS NULL;
```